# As a professional developer is it a must to have a paid version of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've seen the express edition of visual studio and it looks great, something you wouldn't expect to be free. I'm curious, however, if as a professional developer (C# mostly) can you work with just the express edition ? Is it worth investing the money in the professional or ultimate edition?

Thank you.

Comment: Regardless of the IDE you use, make sure you check the licensing information.  Some student editions, demos, and other such 'free' IDEs. have clauses which indicate they are not licensed for commercial development.

Comment: @DGH: Commercial development with the Visual Studio Express editions is OK. See http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/support-faq.aspx.

Comment: This question is more suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com, I think.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Thanks for the info and link.  I never got around to checking VS Express, but I've run into the licensing issue elsewhere.

Comment: I seem to remember older Express versions (2005 and maybe 2008) did have a clause against commercial use. Just to be complete.

Comment: Might have been MSDNAA licensed 'Pro' Editions. They do indeed have such clause.

Answer (score 2):

> As a professional developer is it a must to have a paid version of Visual Studio ?

No.

There's [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) and there's [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) which are great and sometimes even greater then VS. You can use whatever you want, as long as you get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can work with the Express edition. Nothing in the EULA forbids you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see the difference :
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products

In any case framework is the same. The difference is additional product features across different VS versions.

If you are home developer, Express may be good enough.  For a company it a must to have something better.

Comment: And those "additional product features" are usually things designed to make developing and testing easier, but you can usually accomplish the same things with Express through manual processes.  I would highly recommend you download a trial or CTP to test out these features and decide whether they are really useful.  I tend to find some of these "Wizards" and other extras to seem helpful at first, but I soon find them to be lacking in some blaring way that makes them useless.  So don't drop cash(and time learning these features) on these things until you have tried them out thoroughly.

Comment: @AaronLS: +1, Visual Studio and all it's automation is great to start out with...but at some point it's just starting to get in your way.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Express edition is perfectly fine for professional development - both legally and technically. However, you might soon miss some of the features of the professional and higher versions - especially if you're used to them. ;-) Things that come to mind are refactoring (only very basic in VS2010 Express) and the lack of solution folders in project explorer (for solutions consisting of more than a few projects).

Comment: Profiling is another such feature.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do Windows Mobile development but discovered it is not possible in VS Express version. So you must pay for VS if you want to do Windows Mobile development.